# Override content-type for HEAD request

Tags: http, response, content-type, jersey-2.0, jboss6.x

I Have a web application which is making a HEAD call before making actual GET call. The GET method produces application/json. When there is an error say (500) the content-type of the HEAD changes to text/html. For same error the content-type for GET remains application/json. Is there a way to override the content-type being returned in HEAD. This is how I am forming the response. This is a jersery implementation.

```
Response.status(errorStatus)entity( some json).build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manish.

I bet the org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve is squashing your response.

Take a look at the "report" method of that class. If the response is 4xx or 5xx and it has no content (i.e. no entity - which a HEAD response does not have) (line 153) then...
[image: ErrorReportValve::report::153]

set the `content-type` to `text/html` (line 283). Your response has just been squashed, but...
[image: ErrorReportValve::report::283]

ErrorReportValve does not do anything to the response if it has already been committed (line 102).
[image: ErrorReportValve::invoke::102]

So, maybe try creating a servlet filter that commits the response before the ErrorReportValve squashes it? Something like this https://gist.github.com/danmork/bf8c468141fa004298928a1ad9b31746, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Dan. This resolved my issue. I still wonder why it quashes the response on line 283.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure. My best guess is that they were probably thinking about what to do when exceptions happen before the handler (servlet) was able to write anything to the buffer (hence the check for no content). It seems like a failure to not check the request method (e.g. HEAD).